# On some machines my app fails reading a JSON feed from a web Address

Tags: json, uwp

I have a UWP app using C#. I use HttpClient to retrieve a JSON file from the server. On some machines however it fails with a "unable to connect to the remote server". The server is accessible through the browser though. Any ideas?

Comment: Try turning off the Firewall and adding capability of `Private Networks(Client & Server)` in addition to `Internet(Client)` in `Package.appmanifest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpClient has a Timeout property. Set that to the timeout you want and handle the TimeoutException to do specific things on the timeout.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
try
{
    response = await client.GetAsync(url);
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    // handle the timeout, e.g. return false
    return false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the other errors, e.g. throw it
    throw (ex);
}
```